# php report is very slow and crashes in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, crash

I have a report that runs and returns 366 records, each containing a thumbnail that is 104 x 80 px. The issue is that the report runs very slowley even though I increased the memory size.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
ini_set('max_execution_time','600');
```

After writing the SQL query I generate the table items here

```
generate_table_items($query_all_items);
```

This then runs through and checks for the image in the columns

```
function generate_table_items($query){
        $columns = array();
        $resultset = array();

        $scriptname = array();
        $scriptname[0] = "/reports/all_items.php";
        $scriptname[1] = "/reports/all_items_by_value.php";
        $columncount = 0;

        $rowcost = 0;
        $rowsale = 0;

        while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            if (empty($columns)) {

                $columns = array_keys($row);
                echo '<tr><th scope="col" >'.implode('</th><th scope="col" >',get_column_name($columns)).'</th></tr>';
                $columncount = sizeof(array_keys($row));
            }
            $resultset[] = $row;

            echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>',report_image_check($row)).'</td></tr>';

            if(in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)){
                $colspan = (count($columns)-2);
                echo "<tr><th scope='row'>Documents</th><td colspan='$colspan' >";
                    $PKID = $row['ID'];

                    if($row['SumOfTotalCost'] || $row['SumOfSalePrice']){
                        $rowcost += $row['SumOfTotalCost'];
                        $rowsale += $row['SumOfSalePrice'];
                        $get_total = true;
                    }

                    $query_docs = mssql_query("select documents.* from dbo.documents where documents.Antiquities_id = $PKID") or die ('get docs query failed ' . mssql_get_last_message());
                    while($row_docs = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_docs)){
                        $document = "../documents/" . $row_docs['document'];
                        echo "<a href='$document' title='opens in a new window' target='_blank' >" . $row_docs['document'] . "</a> | ";
                    } // End while (list docs)
                    mssql_free_result($query_docs);         
                echo "</td></tr>";
                myflush();
            } // End if all items and all items by value report

        } // End While
        echo '<tr>';
        for($i=0;$i < $columncount-4;$i++){
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo '<td>Total Cost '. $rowcost.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Total Sale '. $rowsale.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Total Calculated Difference '. ($rowsale-$rowcost).'</td></tr>';

} // End function

function get_column_name($columns){
$newcol = array();
$scriptname = array();
$scriptname[0] = "/reports/all_items.php";
$scriptname[1] = "/reports/all_items_by_value.php";
$thecount = 0;
foreach($columns as $col) {
    if($thecount == 1 && in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)) {
        // Don't list the PK
    } else {
        $newcol[] = '<img id="'.$col.'" src="../images/icons/arrow_down.png" alt="click to sort by" onclick="sortby(\''.$col.'\');"  />' . $col;
    }
$thecount++;    
}

/*if(in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)){
    $newcol[] = "documents";
}*/

return $newcol;
}

function report_image_check($row){
global $base_url, $uploaded_images_folder;
$newrow = array();
$imageext = array();

$imageext[0] = ".jpg";
$imageext[1] = ".png";
$imageext[2] = ".gif";
$imageext[3] = ".tiff";

$scriptname = array();
$scriptname[0] = "/reports/all_items.php";
$scriptname[1] = "/reports/all_items_by_value.php";
$PKID = 0;
$thecount = 0;

foreach($row as $rn) {

    if(in_array(strtolower(substr($rn,-4)),$imageext)){
        $small_img_ext = substr($rn,-4);
        $small_img = substr($rn,0,strripos($rn,"."));
        $small_img = $small_img . '_140_105' . $small_img_ext;
        $newrow[] = '<a href="' . $base_url . $uploaded_images_folder . '/' . $small_img . '" title="click to zoom on image" target="_blank" ><img src="' . $base_url . $uploaded_images_folder . '/' . $rn . '" alt="" width="50px" height="50px" /></a>';
    } elseif($thecount == 1 && in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)) {
        $PKID = $rn;
    } elseif($thecount == 2 && in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)) {
        $newrow[] = "<a href='../index.php?template=10&amp;PKID=$PKID' target='_blank' >$PKID (click to view)</a>";
    } else {
        $newrow[] = $rn;
    }

    $thecount++;
    myflush();
}

/*if (in_array($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],$scriptname)) {
    $newrow[] = "<a href='#&amp;PKID=$PKID' target='_blank' >Documents (click to view)</a>";
}*/

return $newrow;

} // End function

//// Flushing function
function myflush(){

ob_implicit_flush(); 
ignore_user_abort();
}
```

Can anyone see an issue with this code or see why it would take so long or why it crashes firefox? Would printing to pdf function work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll take a long time because you're nesting SQL queries... executing a second SQL query for every result that has been returned by the first query.... Doing a single query with a JOIN should help performance significantly.

Printing to PDF would almost certainly be slower: you'd eithe rneed a lot of code to position everything correctly in the report yourself, or to use one of the libraries that can take HTML and render it to a PDF (as you're already generating HTML anyway at the moment, this would be additional processing)

Comment: Right aha (not the band). I'll try that.

Comment: Ok I actually took out the documents query entirely (so only looping over the results on one query entirerly) and it still crashes. :o( And with a join it would return multiple rows as there can be more than one document per item in the database.

Comment: With the join, you can execute a simple "if" test to match against the value for one of the "first table" columns (such as the PK), branching the code as appropriate. It requires a bit more PHP logic, but reduces the number of database queries that you execute from 367 to 1... that guarantees you a performance saving. Why it's crashing in FF is another matter.

Comment: Yeah thanks. It works perfect in Chrome. I guess FF is not the best option for running the report at the moment. We don't need that additional query now anyway. But I see what you are saying here.